# DBeaver Code Completion shows no proposals when using lower case

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, dbeaver

I've just started using DBeaver and I have a problem with Code Completion. When I type in lowercase and trigger auto-complete, there are no proposals, but when I use uppercase it works as it should. I find it a little bit inconvenient since I set it to reformat keywords to uppercase but I still have to spend my day on the shift key because Auto Completion can't handle the lowercase. Is there any way how to fix this?

**Here is lowercase example:**

[image]

**Here with uppercase example:**

[image]

**Here is my Code Completion settings:**

[image]

**Here is my Formatting settings:**

[image]

I use DBeaver version **Version 22.1.5.202208211008**

Answer (score 0):

I think this case is just an instance of a typo. In the first image you typed `refence` (should be `referen` in lowercase), while in the second image you typed `REFEREN`. These two entries will yield different results.